# Notice: Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\VENDO-ECOLOGICO\action.php on line 16

Tags: php

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';

if(isset($_POST['action'])) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM merchandise WHERE category !=''";

    if(isset($_POST['category'])) {
        $category = implode("','", $_POST['category']);
        $query .="AND category IN('".$category."')";
    }


    $result = $con->query($query);
    $output='';

    if($result->num_rows>0){
        while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
            $output .='<div class="col-md-3 mb-2">
            <div class="card-deck">
            <div class="card product" >
                <img src="image/merchandise/'.$row['image'].'" class="card-img-top image">
                <div class="card-img-overlay">
                    <h6 style="margin-top: 25px;" class="text-light text-center bg-info text-center rounded p-1">'.$row['name'].'></h6>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="text-center">
                    Points: '.$row['points'].'><br>
                    Available: <'.$row['availability'].'> 
                    </p>
                    <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="details.php?id=<'.$row['id'].'>" class="btn-success btn-block">DETAILS</a>
                </div>

            </div>
            </div>
            </div>';
        }
    }

    else{
        $output = "<h3>No Merchandise Found!</h3>";
    }
    echo $output;


}


?>
```

Comment: Hey Paul, please edit your question to a minimum viable code snippet and formulate a short question what your problem is :)

Answer (score 0):

If you used mysqli then use mysqli_num_rows() method to check

Comment: so what will can i do because im beginner in coding, can i send to my file and fix it?

Comment: Ok send it,i will check